# Formula for Calculation in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, equation

I need some help in writing a formula in excel with data from the cell H2 as 'x' and O2 as 'n' for the following equation.

```
x/1!+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+.....+x^n/n!
```

Is there a way to write a formula for this in excel and update a cell with resultant data?

Comment: can you put your formula into parantheses, plz? so that we can know what is what. is it like this mathematically: 
`(x)/(1!)+(x^2)/(2!)+(x^3)/(3!)+...+(x^n)/(n!)`  please confirm

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Formula in C2 is

```
{=SUM($A2^ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,$B2))/FACT(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,$B2))))}
```

This is an array formula. Put it into the cell without the curly brackets and then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to finish.

Edit:
prepared for copying downwards

`ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,$B2))` = `{1;2;3;...;n}` with `$B2` = n

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to achieve this:

```
=(H2)/FACT(1)+(H2^2)/FACT(2)+(H2^3)/FACT(3)+....+(H2^O2)/FACT(O2)
```

hope it solves it.